# why is cy.viewport(width, height) not updating screen size?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm using cypress with javascript. I try to change the viewport size to `1280x720` but then when I print out the width to console it stills shows the default `1000`. I am not setting the size to `1000` anywhere

```js
  it('top screenshot', () => {
    cy.viewport(1280, 720)
    const viewportWidth = Cypress.config('viewportWidth')
    cy.task('log', `viewportWidth: ${viewportWidth}`) // viewportWidth: 1000
  })
```

Looking at the [doc](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/viewport) I can't see what I'm doing wrong. I do have a `cy.viewport(1280, 720)` in the `beforeEach(..)` call as well

I am trying to work with a plugin ([Applitools](https://applitools.com/)), but I tried another Cypress plugin ([cypress-visual-regression](https://github.com/cypress-visual-regression/cypress-visual-regression)) to make sure Applitools wasn't messing this up, and that had the same issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be a bug. There's an issue [Values set from command does not override values set in configuration file #22688](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/22688), not exactly the same but in the same area.

There are a couple of alternatives

```js
it('top screenshot', () => {

  Cypress.config('viewportWidth', 1280)
  cy.wrap(Cypress.config('viewportWidth')).should('eq', 1280)   // passing
})
```

```js
it('top screenshot', {viewportWidth: 1280, viewportHeight: 1000}, () => {

  cy.wrap(Cypress.config('viewportWidth')).should('eq', 1280)   // passing
})
```

---

The `viewport:changed` event is still being fired, so if you have a lot of `cy.viewport()` commands you can patch the event to make them continue to work.

```js
Cypress.on('viewport:changed', (newValue) => {
  Cypress.config('viewportWidth', newValue.viewportWidth)   // this works
  Cypress.config('viewportHeight', newValue.viewportHeight)
})

it('top screenshot', () => {

  cy.viewport(1280, 720)

  cy.then(() => {
    cy.wrap(Cypress.config('viewportWidth')).should('eq', 1280)  // passes
    cy.wrap(Cypress.config('viewportHeight')).should('eq', 720)  // passes
  })
})
```

Note, I assert the values inside a `.then()` because the command queue should run before the assertion is done.

To patch globally, add `Cypress.on('viewport:changed', ...)` in `/cypress/support/e2e.js`.

Comment: That isn't working for me. And I also discovered through screenshots that `cy.viewport` is in fact changing the screen size. Meanwhile setting `Cypress.config('viewportWidth', newWidth)` and `Cypress.config('viewportHeight', newHeight)` doesn't actually actually change the screen size. So maybe we got mixed up on how to measure viewport size on this? There doesn't seem to be a function to report that

Comment: That's a pity, it works fine for me. Are you sure you're looking in the right place?. The config isn't necessarily the current size, it's just the configuration settings. I guess if you ask Cypress they might tell you that `cy.viewport()` isn't actually meant to modify the *configuration*.

Comment: "The config isn't necessarily the current size" Yeah,  I think thats what I was missing. But this is kinda weird. I tried it using [this minimal repo](https://github.com/syntapy/cypress-bug-demo/tree/a96f0e5ab811e4e5793aa2de7b1db25482ad6d0d) to play around with it

Comment: One of the problems in the mini-repo is you're running synchronous code at the end to get the new values, but the `cy.viewport()` command runs on the queue and it hasn't run yet by the time `const vpWidthNew = ...` is executed. If you put a `cy.then(() => {...})` callback around that bottom section, you get different (better?) results.

Comment: Also note the Cypress GUI shows new size `1100x760`.

Comment: Oh, I totally missed the `cy.then` part you mentioned. Yeah doing the getters & assertions inside the `cy.then` does fix it. Thanks for your help. But also note that for me removing the event handler modification you mentioned doesn't break it either